# Does improving the page load speed decrease user session duration?

Tags: google-analytics, page-speed, session

My website loaded in 10 seconds, then I improved the site's performance. I introduced a cache, minified files, and compressed images. This reduced the load speed to under 2 seconds.

Is this why the average session duration of my users dropped? Could it be because for every page the user loads they save themselves 8 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - all else being equal - decreasing your load time will decrease your average session duration.

Session duration is the time between the first and last interaction hit on your site (an interaction hit being either a pageview or an event that isn't marked as non-interaction).

So GA doesn't care how someone spends that time - whether it's waiting for the page to load or actually browsing.

You should be able to see this using the Page Timings report (Behaviour > Site Speed > Page Timing) and clicking on *Technical* at the top (under the *Explorer* tab).

A few caveats:

- this assumes that you've put the tracking tag in the right place, which is immediately after the opening `<head>` tag
- exit pages have no time on page, as there is only one timestamp available to calculate with (and therefore bounced visits have no session duration)

Comment: Thanks for the insight, it's new to me that a bounce will have no session duration. This may also explain a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the time on site is now dropping. But did you also check the bounce rate? But better page performance is never a decline.

Tip: The absolute value of "time on site" is useless. You have to check your values against your competitors in your specific niche.